# `tensorflowjs_converter` causing model in browser to not detect any objects

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I am building an object detection model for tensorflow.js from "ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8". I have trained the model and converted it with the `tensorflowjs_converter` cli tool. When I run the model in jupyter, I get this output:

[image: jupyter output]

But when I load the model into tensorflow.js, it doesn't find any bounding boxes. It does spit out something in the bounding box tensor, which looks like this:

[image: tfjs model output]

Mostly random. None of those boxes have a class associated with them. Initially, I thought the tfjs model was less accurate, since it looks like the converter runs through some optimizations. But after improving the accuracy in the python notebook the tfjs accuracy has not increased.

It does not look like there is a way to turn off the `tensorflowjs_converter` optimizations. Is that true?

Is there anything else I can try to get my model to run in tfjs?

Here is my `pipeline_file.config`:

```
# SSD with Mobilenet v2 FPN-lite (go/fpn-lite) feature extractor, shared box
# predictor and focal loss (a mobile version of Retinanet).
# Retinanet: see Lin et al, https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02002
# Trained on COCO, initialized from Imagenet classification checkpoint
# Train on TPU-8
#
# Achieves 28.2 mAP on COCO17 Val

model {
  ssd {
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
    num_classes: 6
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: [1.0, 2.0, 0.5]
        scales_per_octave: 2
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 640
        width: 640
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        depth: 128
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.6
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.01
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            scale: true,
            decay: 0.997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
        num_layers_before_predictor: 4
        share_prediction_tower: true
        use_depthwise: true
        kernel_size: 3
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpn_keras'
      use_depthwise: true
      fpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        additional_layer_depth: 128
      }
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          random_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.01
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          scale: true,
          decay: 0.997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          alpha: 0.25
          gamma: 2.0
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/content/drive/MyDrive/nespresso_detection/models/research/deploy/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  batch_size: 16
  sync_replicas: true
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  num_steps: 8000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_object_covered: 0.0
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.75
      max_aspect_ratio: 3.0
      min_area: 0.75
      max_area: 1.0
      overlap_thresh: 0.0
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: .08
          total_steps: 50000
          warmup_learning_rate: .026666
          warmup_steps: 1000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
}

train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "/content/drive/MyDrive/nespresso_detection/train/VertuoPlus_label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/content/drive/MyDrive/nespresso_detection/train/VertuoPlus.tfrecord"
  }
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "/content/drive/MyDrive/nespresso_detection/train/VertuoPlus_label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/content/drive/MyDrive/nespresso_detection/valid/VertuoPlus.tfrecord"
  }
}
```

Here is the `model.json` file the converter creates:

```
{
    "format": "graph-model",
    "generatedBy": "2.4.0",
    "convertedBy": "TensorFlow.js Converter v2.8.3",
    "signature": {
        "inputs": {
            "input_tensor:0": {
                "name": "input_tensor:0",
                "dtype": "DT_UINT8",
                "tensorShape": {
                    "dim": [
                        {
                            "size": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "size": "-1"
                        },
                        {
                            "size": "-1"
                        },
                        {
                            "size": "3"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "outputs": {
            "Identity_1:0": {
                "name": "Identity_1:0",
                "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
                "tensorShape": {
                    "dim": [
                        {
                            "size": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "size": "100"
                        },
                        {
                            "size": "4"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Identity_3:0": {
                "name": "Identity_3:0",
                "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
                "tensorShape": {
                    "dim": [
                        {
                            "size": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "size": "100"
                        },
                        {
                            "size": "7"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Identity_5:0": {
                "name": "Identity_5:0",
                "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
                "tensorShape": {
                    "dim": [
                        {
                            "size": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Identity:0": {
                "name": "Identity:0",
                "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
                "tensorShape": {
                    "dim": [
                        {
                            "size": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "size": "100"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Identity_7:0": {
                "name": "Identity_7:0",
                "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
                "tensorShape": {
                    "dim": [
                        {
                            "size": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "size": "51150"
                        },
                        {
                            "size": "7"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Identity_2:0": {
                "name": "Identity_2:0",
                "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
                "tensorShape": {
                    "dim": [
                        {
                            "size": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "size": "100"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Identity_4:0": {
                "name": "Identity_4:0",
                "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
                "tensorShape": {
                    "dim": [
                        {
                            "size": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "size": "100"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Identity_6:0": {
                "name": "Identity_6:0",
                "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
                "tensorShape": {
                    "dim": [
                        {
                            "size": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "size": "51150"
                        },
                        {
                            "size": "4"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "modelTopology": {
        "node": [
            {
                "name": "StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/PadOrClipBoxList/zeros_7",
                "op": "Const",
                "attr": {
                    "dtype": {
                        "type": "DT_INT32"
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "tensor": {
                            "dtype": "DT_INT32",
                            "tensorShape": {
                                "dim": [
                                    {
                                        "size": "1"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
... to many nodes to list here ...
            {
                    "name": "ConstantFolding/StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/stack_7_const_axis",
                    "shape": [],
                    "dtype": "int32"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And my converter script (for what it is worth):

```
!tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format=tf_saved_model \
    --output_format=tfjs_graph_model \
    --signature_name=serving_default \
    --saved_model_tags=serve \
    ./saved_model \
    ./tfjs
```

Comment: Are you preprocessing the images in the same way as you did when training the model?

Comment: I am using the object detection script `model_main_tf2.py` detailed here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_training_and_evaluation.md
I have dug into the code and do not see any pre-processing. That being said, there are a lot of layers of code to look through and I could have missed something. 

Is there an easy way to see if there is any pre-processing being run?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, there were a couple things going on.

1. the WASM backend was return different numbers, and may be incorrect. I have not been able to fully parse the output from the WASM backend.
2. With the CPU or webgl backends, the output tensors are not labeled, so some guessing is required to interpret the data. The model will always output 100 bounding boxes. One tensor will have the accuracy score, one will have the classification for that object (integer values), one will have the coordinates (floats, percentages from the top left corner), and one will have the raw classification data (floats, an accuracy rating for each class, in my case, in the shape of (1,100,7)).

The first step was to understand what the output tensors mean and then filter out the objects that have a low score ( < .8). I then had to match the classes to the integer values they were given, which possibly had changed since labeling. Then the data made sense.

I hope this gives other people a good path to take if you get lost in the data as I was.

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you were able to understand the output tensors and how you processed the output? Thanks!

Comment: You will just have to connect them with the data you put into your model. Each model will be configured differently. Start by filtering out objects that have a low accuracy. If there no objects with a high accuracy, check that you are passing the image into your model correctly.